# How to get the transaction ID from Hyperledger Sawtooth

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

When I am making a transaction with the JS sdk to my docker sawtooth node, I am getting a response which contains only a link which shows this data:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "87be1095b29372fff3b46d4f0eb0f354514208d8ef612877bae0216e70d4931f302e2b2f3741d52e22acf92c7e3f3935775b503a43f45a7297d1ce5ad76b9bb2",
      "invalid_transactions": [],
      "status": "COMMITTED"
    }
  ],
  "link": "http://localhost:8008/batch_statuses?id=87be1095b29372fff3b46d4f0eb0f354514208d8ef612877bae0216e70d4931f302e2b2f3741d52e22acf92c7e3f3935775b503a43f45a7297d1ce5ad76b9bb2"
}
```

Now this id appears to be the batch-id. How can I get the transaction id e.g. to make a query to get this transaction only?

Comment: You can use `/blocks` REST-API endpoint. It list the transactions. Their ID in the output is the signed TransactionHeader value.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that you can also take the transaction id out of the transaction building steps. I assumed, that the id gets created from the validator, but seems like its just generated and sent from the client.

Comment: Yes, the fact that the ID is generated at submission time doesn't jump out at you in the docs.